# Trying to understand how to create an async function in rust that returns a MySqlPool object

Tags: mysql, rust

I'm trying to learn rust and Actix web with sqlx, I've got a function that should return a MySqlPool struct to a controller function, this is I have so far

file conn.rs

```
use sqlx::mysql::{MySqlPool, MySqlPoolOptions};
use std::future::Future;

pub async fn connect() -> Future<Output = sqlx::Result<MySqlPool>> {
//pub async fn connect() -> sqlx::Result<MySqlPool> {
    let pool = MySqlPoolOptions::new()
                .max_connections(5)
                .connect("mysql://file:file@localhost:34536t/file").await?;
}
```

file controllers.rs

```
use actix_web::{get, /*post,*/ HttpResponse, Responder};
use sqlx::mysql::{MySqlPool};

#[path= "conn.rs"]
mod conn;
use conn::connect;

#[get("/")]
pub async fn home() -> impl Responder {
    let c: Result<MySqlPool> = connect().await;
    match c {
        Ok(v) => {
            let row = sqlx::query_as("SELECT id FROM persons LIMIT 1")
                                        .fetch_one(&v).await;
            HttpResponse::Ok().body("good!")
        },
        Err(v) => {
            HttpResponse::Ok().body("bad!")
        }
    }

}
```

When I run cargo build I got this error
error[E0782]: trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword

If I add the dyn keyword I've got other errors, can you please help to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You will get this error any time you try to return a trait from a function rather than a concrete type that implements the trait because trait objects are not `Sized` so they must be heap-allocated (which is why the compiler usually tries to helpfully suggest something like `dyn Box<T>`. In this case I'm pretty sure you do actually want `dyn Future` and you should probably be asking about the other errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for async functions does not include the returned `Future`, it is implicit:

```rust
pub async fn connect() -> sqlx::Result<MySqlPool> {
    let pool = MySqlPoolOptions::new()
                .max_connections(5)
                .connect("mysql://file:file@localhost:34536t/file").await?;
}
```

If you want to specify it explicitly (usually you don't but there are some valid reasons, like wanting to return `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>`), you get rid of `async` and return `impl Future`:

```rust
pub fn connect() -> impl Future<Output = sqlx::Result<MySqlPool>> {
    async move {
        let pool = MySqlPoolOptions::new()
                .max_connections(5)
                .connect("mysql://file:file@localhost:34536t/file").await?;
    }
}
```